# Calling 'make' from Python inside Vagrant VM

Tags: python, ubuntu, gcc, makefile, vagrant

Okay, so this question is very project-specific, but it's a problem for me nonetheless.

I have a Python/django website, hosted on localhost from an Ubuntu VM set up by Vagrant. From this website I want to paste in C code and compile it via a series of Python functions. In one of these functions I call `make` like this:

```
arg2 = os.path.join(Default_SDK_PATH, "examples/peripheral/blinky")
arg4 = os.path.join(Default_SDK_PATH, "examples/peripheral/blinky/makefile")
args = ' '.join(['make', '-C', arg2, '-f', arg4])

p = subprocess.Popen(
    args,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True
)
output, errors = p.communicate()
p.wait()
```

I specify `arg2` and `arg4` more for testing than anything else - It's just to be 100% sure that the correct makefile is used.

#### ### ### ###

OK!
So my problem comes when the subprocess runs. The makefile is called with `make`, but failes. When I check the build log I can see the error message `arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: nano.specs: No such file or directory`.

When I call `vagrant up` for the first time a file named bootstrap.sh is called. I've tried adding new commands to this file

```
sudo apt-get remove binutils-arm-none-eabi gcc-arm-none-eabi
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:terry.guo/gcc-arm-embedded
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi=4.9.3.2015q1-0trusty13
```

to uninstall Ubuntu's original GCC and install the latest GCC toolchain. No success there either. I've also tried returning the whole filestructure to file just to check if the files in question exists, and they do!

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you successfully execute that command just from the terminal, and in the same working directory as you are launching the script?

Comment: @skrrgwasme The project used in the Vagrant VM have entirely different directories for the project and the SDK that I use. But I have an identical copy of the project on my host machine where the file paths match the host setup, and I can call `make` there without any problems.

Comment: @skrrgwasme In addition: The Vagrant VM is a closed box that I can't access due to various reasons.

Comment: can you include the make command in the bootstrap file?  Just trying to eliminate if there's issue with environment your python/c is running.

Answer (score 0):

Whoop-di-hoo, I solved it!

I don't exactly know *why*, but `sudo apt-get remove binutils-arm-none-eabi gcc-arm-none-eabi` doesn't seem to do anything, so the original GCC-files still exist when I try to install the new GCC.

Also, the new GCC is installed in `/usr/bin`, while the old GCC has it's own specified folder.

So I edited my Makefile to get `arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.9.3` from `/usr/bin` instead of the old `arm-none-eabi-gcc`. `nano.specs` is now included, and life is great!